# How can I fix this problem with loading to Home Screen?

Tags: android, kotlin

The problem I'm facing is that when the user is logged in and the user opens the app, first the splash screen appears then the usual behavior of the app should be that the user should see the Home Screen but the onboarding screen appears for a fraction of seconds, which should not happen. Also, I'm using the new SplashAPI and Android Compose. What would be the best possible solution for this? I'm providing the snippets of code related:

MainActivity.kt:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var splashViewModel: SplashViewModel


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition {
           !splashViewModel.isLoading.value
        }

        setContent {
            FoodikeTheme {
                val screen by splashViewModel.startDestination

                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                ) {
                    SetupNavigation(
                        startDestination = screen
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SetupNavigation(startDestination: String) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(
        navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination
    ) {
        composable(
            route = Screen.Onboarding.route,
        ) {
            OnBoarding(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(
            route = Screen.LoginScreen.route,
        ) {
            LoginScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(
            route = Screen.HomeScreen.route
        ) {
            HomeScreen()
        }
    }


}
```

SplashViewModel.kt:

```
class SplashViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: LoginRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _isLoading: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(true)
    val isLoading = _isLoading.asStateFlow()

    private val _startDestination: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf(Screen.Onboarding.route)
    val startDestination: State<String> = _startDestination

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {

            repository.readLoginState().collect { completed ->
                if (completed) {
                    _startDestination.value = Screen.HomeScreen.route
                } else {
                    _startDestination.value = Screen.Onboarding.route
                }
            }
            _isLoading.value = false
        }

    }
}
```

LoginRepository.kt

```
class LoginRepositoryImpl(context: Context):LoginRepository {

    private object PreferencesKey {
        val onBoardingKey = booleanPreferencesKey(name = "on_login_completed")
    }

    private val dataStore = context.dataStore

    override suspend fun saveLoginState(completed: Boolean) {
        dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[PreferencesKey.onBoardingKey] = completed
        }
    }

    override fun readLoginState(): Flow<Boolean> {
        return dataStore.data
            .catch { exception ->
                if (exception is IOException) {
                    emit(emptyPreferences())
                } else {
                    throw exception
                }
            }
            .map { preferences ->
                val onBoardingState = preferences[PreferencesKey.onBoardingKey] ?: false
                onBoardingState
            }
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel.kt:

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: LoginRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _email = mutableStateOf("")
    val email: State<String> = _email

    private val _password = mutableStateOf("")
    val password: State<String> = _password

    fun changeEmail(mail: String) {
        _email.value = email.value.replace(email.value, mail)

    }

    fun changePassword(pass: String) {
        _password.value = password.value.replace(password.value, pass)
    }

    fun saveOnBoardingState(completed: Boolean) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.saveLoginState(completed = completed)
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What if you move `_isLoading.value = false` into the `collect` method?

Comment: same result as previous

Comment: I guess a workaround could be to delay setting `_isLoading`. The onboarding screen is probably shown because that's what's shown first, and then when `startDestination` is changed, the splash screen disappears immediately, while it takes some time to switch from the onboarding screen to the regular home screen.

Comment: should I use delay() function?

Comment: Yes, at least I think it's worth a try.

Comment: I put the delay function in the splash viewmodel's init block in the viewModelscope... it didn't work

Comment: What if you do this instead of delay? `Timer().schedule(500) {
  _isLoading.value = false
}`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Compose or the Splash API, but can you remove the default `_startDestination` value?

`private val _startDestination: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf()`

instead of

`private val _startDestination: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf(Screen.Onboarding.route)`

I feel like what's happening is `val screen by splashViewModel.startDestination` is kicking off the creation of the `SplashViewModel`, and then reading the current value, which is initialised to the `Onboarding` screen.

As soon as you get that value the navigation happens, but meanwhile the `SplashViewModel` is running its coroutine you started in `init`, loading the preference from your `DataStore` asynchronously (which is slow, which is why it's still happening) and eventually it updates `startDestination` to `HomeScreen`.

When the observer in `MainActivity` gets that updated value, it navigates to the other screen - but only after having navigated to `Onboarding` for a moment. Maybe the navigation is the slow part here, so it can only divert away after it's *finished* displaying and initialising `Onboarding`, which is long enough for the user to see it for a moment.

So instead of giving `startDestination` a default value, you could leave it blank. Your `init` code is running a coroutine that will initialise it with *something* soon! Like I said, I haven't used Compose so I don't know what it's actually doing, but if it's using the reactive observer pattern it *should* be fine to leave `startDestination` with no value, so it acts when a value is pushed. *I assume* anyway! Worth a try

Comment: It results in crashing the app as `startDestination` parameter in the `NavHost` in the MainActivity receives a blank parameter.

Comment: You are correct that as the key the DataStore is retrieved asynchronously, the default value is assigned to the `_startDestination` and when the value is successfully retrieved the value of the `_startDestination` changes and so does the screen.

Comment: I'm thinking of using SharedPreferences instead of DataStore but it would have been better with DataStore

Comment: @GautamHazarika yeah if that's the case then I'm not sure, sorry - I haven't used Compose at all so I don't know what it's doing or what the expectations are. If that's setting the `startDestination` in a Navigation graph by trying to read the current `value` (instead of `observing` it) then yeah that would be an issue. The usual way you'd do this is to have *HomeScreen* as the (fixed) start destination, and then conditionally navigate to *Onboarding* if required, similar to this: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional Not sure about the Compose approach, sorry!